# HTML table cell width

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this code that displays info from an XML file in an HTML table. I want to make one cell bigger than the other. I tried using

```
<td width="70%">
```

But this didn't solve my issue.

Part of my code :

```
 <table bgcolor="#00FF00"></table>
 <style type="text/css">
  table,th,td {border : 5px solid #F7B896; border-collapse: collapse;}
  th,td { padding-top: 10px; background-color:white;}
  table {style=width:100%;}
  </style>

for (i = 0; i < songTitles.length; i++) {
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    songTime[i].attributes.getNamedItem("StartTime").nodeValue +
    "</td><td><b>" +
    artistNames[i].attributes.getNamedItem("name").nodeValue +
    "</b> - " +
    songTitles[i].attributes.getNamedItem("title").nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>"
```

Here is my full code: https://newfmplayer.online/loadxml
And here is how my table looks https://newfmplayer.online/lastaired.html.
I want to make artist and song name bigger, and the time cell smaller.

Comment: You need to specify the total witdth for the table itself, otherwise percents can't be calculated.

Comment: @Teemu I did wrote in <table width="100%">, it stil did not work. Maybe I put it in wrong place

Comment: Use CSS instead of elements' attributes ..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITED**:

So let's be more accurate, best approach will be to add a class to the td's you want bigger than add that class to the tag, you had also a typo in css

```
 <style type="text/css">
 table,th,td {border : 5px solid #F7B896; border-collapse: collapse;}
 th,td { padding-top: 10px; background-color:white;}
 td.bigger{width:70%}
 table {width:100%;}
</style>
<table bgcolor="#00FF00"></table>


<script>
  for (i = 0; i < songTitles.length; i++) {
    table += "<tr><td>" +   //assuming you want the second bigger
        songTime[i].attributes.getNamedItem("StartTime").nodeValue +"</td><td class='bigger'><b>" +
        artistNames[i].attributes.getNamedItem("name").nodeValue + "</b> - " + 
        songTitles[i].attributes.getNamedItem("title").nodeValue + "</td></tr>"

</script>
```

Comment: hi it did not worked for me. I wrote it like : "</td><td><b>"<td colspan="2"> + artistNames[i].attributes.getNamedItem("name").nodeValue + "</td></b>       Correct me if I'm wrong